# AUX pattern workaround

Tags: scala

This is a question which derives from the [AUX](http://gigiigig.github.io/posts/2015/09/13/aux-pattern.html) pattern.

What is the advantage of having a trait defined like this:

```
trait Unwrap[T[_], R] {
   type Out
   def apply(tr: T[R]): Out
}
```

versus this?

```
trait Unwrap[T[_], R, Out] {
   def apply(tr: T[R]): Out
}
```

The second trait definition eliminates the necessity of using the AUX pattern.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you use the `Aux` pattern is not well defined in your example. The problem comes when the value of the type provided by `Aux` is not yet known, which in most cases implies derivation, and more specifically macro/compile time type derivation.

This is widely used in Shapeless.

```
def test[V1, HL](input: V1)(implicit ev: Generic.Aux[V1, HL])`
```

When you write this, you might think `HL` is an input type to `Aux`, but it's actually an output from within the `Generic` macro, provided as a consumable to `Aux`, e.g the output is magically "injected" into HL, so the output type computed by `Generic.Aux` is accessible through `HL` beyond that call-site.

It exists to circumvent a compiler limitation, if you have multiple implicits in the same param group, where one implicit depends on the `Aux` macro output of the one before.

Pasting from [**The Scala Bible, New Testament, Gospel of Miles**](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/generic.scala#L118):

```
 * More importantly, Aux allows us to write code like this:
   *
   * {{{
   *   def myMethod[T, R]()(implicit eqGen: Generic.Aux[T,R], repEq: Eq[R]) = ???
   * }}}
   *
   * Here, we specify T, and we find a Generic.Aux[T,R] by implicit search. We then use R in the second argument.
   * Generic.Aux[T, R] is exactly equivalent to Generic[T] { type Repr = R }, but Scala doesn't allow us to write
   * it this way:
   *
   * {{{
   *   def myMethod[T, R]()(eqGen: Generic[T] { Repr = R }, reqEq: Eq[egGen.Repr]) = ???
   * }}}
```